# Javascript backwards-aware chaining without parenthesis e.g. expect(x).not.toBe()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, getter, chaining, brackets

Today I wanted to do something with chaining in a similar way to Jasmine: http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/

Jasmine has a very fluid style of writing a test conditional, for example:

```
expect(result).not.toBe(85);
```

In my test I just wanted to add an `and` as some sugar coating that did something like:

```
createRegion('test').and.append()
```

So that was pretty simple (I am aware the following won't work in IE8<):

```
Layout.prototype.__defineGetter__('and', function() {
    return this;
});
```

But that got me interested in how jasmine is:

- doing no-bracket chaining when I can't find any instance of `defineProperty` (IE8<) or `__defineGetter__`
- cannot find where it has defined `not`
- trying to imagine how the method chained after `not` is aware of it - I am assuming a variable is set like `reverse = true` in the `not` method so the proceeding method knows to reverse it's outcome?

How would you implement such behaviour, or otherwise do you know how jasmine has done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the source, and this implementation of expect:

```
jasmine.Spec.prototype.expect = function(actual) {
  var positive = new (this.getMatchersClass_())(this.env, actual, this);
  positive.not = new (this.getMatchersClass_())(this.env, actual, this, true);
  return positive;
};
```

So, the property `not` is the implementation of the same class, receiving this extra parameter to reverse the output:

```
jasmine.Matchers = function(env, actual, spec, opt_isNot) {
  this.env = env;
  this.actual = actual;
  this.spec = spec;
  this.isNot = opt_isNot || false; // reverse option set
  this.reportWasCalled_ = false;
};
```

Finally, in `jasmine.Matchers.matcherFn_`, it uses it to reverse the result:

```
if (this.isNot) {
    result = !result;
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks for taking the time to figure that out, it seems like quite a convoluted implementation but maybe necessary for Jasmine. I think I shall stick to using getters!

Answer (score 1):

here is one way i came up with to pull it off, but if you had lots of methods, you'll want to use getters instead of duplication:

```
function expect(ob){
  var resp={};

  function not(fn){return function(){return !fn.apply(resp, arguments)}; }

  resp.toBe=function(val){;
      return val==ob; 
  };


  var n=resp.not=function(){};

  for(var i in resp){
     var v=resp[i];
     if(v.call){ n[i]=not(v); }
  }

  return resp;
}

// try it out on a number:
var x=123;

expect(x).not.toBe(123); // false
expect(x).not.toBe(321); // true
expect(x).toBe(123);     // true
```

please note this is a highly simplified demo; i don't vouch that it's a great performer, and i don't know how jasmine actually works, but is does what you want given the constraints.
i think it's neat, but i still like defineProperty better.

Comment: That's neat thanks a lot, it is simplified but good too see a less convoluted implementation than on Jasmine. You answered the question too but I could select only one sorry :)